# rename multiple files in python using dictionary match

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to rename files that are in pythons values in dictionary to the key of that value.

For example:
#dict

`comp_dict = {'ADBL':'397', 'AHPC':'360', 'AKBSL':'2845'}`

os.rename to =  **397.csv to ADBL.csv, 2845.csv to AHPC.csv** and so on.

Tried:

```
import os
for ids in comp_dict.values():
    for ticker in comp_dict.keys():
        ren_src = ids + '.csv'
        ren_out = ticker + '.csv'
        os.rename(ren_src, ren_out)
```

Comment: what error did you get?

Answer (score 3):

```
import os

for dest_name, curr_name in comp_dict.items():
    os.rename(f"{curr_name}.csv", f"{dest_name}.csv")
```

Comment: for dest_name, curr_name in com_id.items():
    try:
        os.rename(f"{curr_name}.csv", f"{dest_name}.csv")
    except WindowsError:
        continue
Thanks it worked but gave me error cuz some files were not there. but managed to continue with try except..